# FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream when using specific location for another website

Tags: php, nginx

I access my website using https://website1.inov.com

If I try to access https://website1.inov.com/backend which is supposed to be another apps, I got an

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading
>   response header from upstream

Below my virtuahost:

```
server {
        server_name website1.inov.com www.website1.inov.com;
        root /var/www/website1/;
        index index.html;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/website1.inov.com.access.log combined if=$log_ua;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/website1.inov.com.error.log;

       # Return a 404 not found for every hidden files
        location ~ /\. {
                deny all;
                return 404;
        }

        location / {
                # Check if a file or directory index file exists, else route it to index.php.
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        location /backend {
                 alias /var/www/backend;
                 index index.php;
                 try_files $uri $uri/ /backend/index.php;

                 location ~* ^/backend/(.*\.php)$ {
                 try_files  $uri $uri/ =404;
                 fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                # fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(.*)$;
                 fastcgi_param PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin;
                 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                 fastcgi_index index.php;
                 fastcgi_param CI_ENV production;
                 fastcgi_param DOMAIN production;
                 include fastcgi.conf;
                }
        }
```

Can you please help me ?
thanks

Comment: The value of `$document_root` is not useful when you are using `alias`. Try `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunatly I still have the same problem..